# symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 (M1 mac)

Tags: c++, terminal, clang, apple-m1

I'm trying to run my c++ program with the following line:

**g++ -I/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/include -L/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/lib model.cpp -lgurobi_c++**

But I get the following error:

**ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Hope someone knows what is going on. I have a M1 macbook.  
Thank you!

***Actualization!*** The library works, when I compile it with a makefile, but when I try in the terminal it does not. This is the actual line I'm trying.

**g++ -o main -m64 -g -Wall -I/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/include -L/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/lib model.cpp -lgurobi_c++**

But the error it throws is still the same.

p.d.: I'm new to c++ and gcc.

Comment: I add a -c in my line: 

g++ -c -I/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/include -L/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/lib diet.cpp -lgurobi_c++

and get the new error this time: 

clang: warning: -lgurobi_c++: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/lib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

Comment: Note that if you're using the XCode tools, `g++` is just a symlink to `clang++`.

Comment: What symbols are actually missing?  It would help to post more detail.  From what you say in the comments below, this is not directly related to arm.